# Random background image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I create a button that changes the background image of the entire website to a random image?

```html
<script>
function randomHero() {
  var heroPics = ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/musician-background-1680.jpg','https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/pink-floyd-division-bell-228953.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/northstar.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/womensrights.jpg'];

  $('body').css({
    'background' : 'url('+ heroPics[Math.floor(Math.random() * heroPics.length)] + ') no-repeat',
    'background-attachment' : 'scroll',
    'background-position' : '50% 50%',
    'background-size' : 'cover'
  });
}

randomHero();
$('button').on('click', randomHero);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you actually included jQuery and created the button? This is working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/gsgzmuy5/

Comment: I've created the button but may be missing the jQuery, what should I include?

Comment: I used jQuery 3.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to include jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function randomHero() {
    var heroPics = ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/musician-background-1680.jpg','https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/pink-floyd-division-bell-228953.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/northstar.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/womensrights.jpg'];

    $('body').css({
      'background' : 'url('+ heroPics[Math.floor(Math.random() * heroPics.length)] + ') no-repeat',
      'background-attachment' : 'scroll',
      'background-position' : '50% 50%',
      'background-size' : 'cover'
    });
  }

  randomHero();

  $('button').on('click', randomHero);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to include jQuery and button too.

```js
function randomHero() {
  var heroPics = ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/musician-background-1680.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/pink-floyd-division-bell-228953.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/northstar.jpg', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/womensrights.jpg'];

  $('body').css({
    'background': 'url(' + heroPics[Math.floor(Math.random() * heroPics.length)] + ') no-repeat',
    'background-attachment': 'scroll',
    'background-position': '50% 50%',
    'background-size': 'cover'
  });
}

randomHero();

$('button').on('click', randomHero);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Change Background</button>
```